# LINQ to SQL - two same databases

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have two SQL servers with the same database. Now I want to copy some data from the first to the second. I created two LINQ to SQL classes, but when I write the query I get an error because of name collisions. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the schema is the same (like it sounds), you should be able to use the same model, but just use different connection-strings / connections to initialize two data-context instances. The *problem* however, is likely to be detaching objects from one model to pass to the other, and all the primary key goodness. In essence, I would recommend *copying the objects* and passing different objects with different keys to the second model.

Also, if the volume is very high, you might find `SqlBulkCopy` coupled to `SqlDataReader` useful; but that doesn't use LINQ-to-SQL *at all*.

Comment: +1 for alternate suggestion that sounds like it may be a better solution